# Resize the cell of CollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to make something like skills page, so I used collection view but I need to to make the width of the sells to resize depends on the skill that the user adds. I just need how to resize the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol and use the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method.

Example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellData = self.data[indexPath.item]
    let skills = cellData.skills // Or fetch the skills from somewhere else

    let width = skills.count * 100
    let height = 100
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```